# I cannot find device_config.json

Tags: google-voice

I'm trying to do something with google-voice-assistant in my PC. 
I did several steps that indicated in github for google assistant SDK.
However, everything is work just except pushtalk. I cannot do anything with it.

[image]

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please do not post links to images of text. Post the text. If you are following a tutorial, it would be helpful to link the tutorial and point out exactly where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you. You need to add a config.json file, read the google-voice-assistant documentation.